# How to use isdigit function to check whether a given multiple digit character is numeric or not?

Tags: c, integer, ascii, cs50

How to use isdigit function in C to check whether the given multiple digit string is numeric or not?
This is how I used isdigit function for a single digit character.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char c = get_char("Enter a single character:");
    int a = isdigit(c);
    if ( a != 0)
    {
        printf("%c is an integer \n", c);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%c is not an integer \n",c);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to check for the multiple digit character(eg. 92, 789). here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main()
{
    string num = get_string(" Enter a number:");
    int final = 1;
    for(int i =0; i< strlen(num); i++)
    {
      // final = final * isdigit(num(i));
      final*= isdigit(num[i]);
    }
    if(final!=0)
    {
        printf("%s is an integer.\n", num);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s is not an integer.\n", num);
    }
}
```

However, the above code only works for two digit integer , but not for 3 digit integer. See this:
[Compiled Code SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIKwZ.png)

Comment: Have you tried the program with a zero-digit integer (an empty string)?

Comment: @Fe2O3 not yet, can you please describe more about it?

Comment: Read your code. A zero-length string will leave `final` set to be `1` meaning an empty string will be incorrectly identified as "an integer".

Answer (score 2):

The [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) function isn't required to return a boolean `0` or `1` value. It's specified to return zero if the character isn't a digit, and *any* non-zero value if it is a digit.

Take for example the implementation used by [here](https://godbolt.org/z/5Ydav7rxh). We can see that `isdigit` returns `2048`.

Because it returns that value, the multiplication will lead to a signed integer arithmetic *overflow*, which in turn leads to *undefined behavior*.

Instead I suggest you use `isdigit` directly in a condition, and if it returns `0` then print the message and terminate the program:

```
size_t length = strlen(num);
if (length == 0)
{
    printf("String is empty\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
    if (isdigit(num[i]) == 0)
    {
        printf("Input was not a number\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}

// Here we know that all characters in the input are digits
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply replace the multiply operation with `&`... Once a non-digit appears and `isdigit()` returns `0` (meaning `false`), the flag variable will remain `false`.

You may want to consider combining operations into compact code such as the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h> // less "generic" that the others

int main( void ) {
    string num = get_string(" Enter a number:");

    int i = 0;
    while( isdigit( num[i] ) ) i++; // loop fails on '\0', too

    if( i == 0 || num[i] ) // empty string or did not reach its end
        printf( "%s is NOT an integer.\n", num );
    else
        printf( "%s is an integer.\n", num );

    return 0;
}
```